# What is meant by the shifting property of the companion form?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, linear, matrix, state-space

I am going through the book "Linear System Theory and Design" by Chi-Tsong Chen, where they talk about the **controllable canonical form** and how it is a realization of a transfer matrix.

In the book, we have the following passage:

[image]

What is this shifting property that they are talking about? The closest thing I can find is this relationship between [Companion Form Matrices and Linear Recurrence Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Linear_recursive_sequences), but not sure how that applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing fancy here, but elementary matrix multiplication and \$A\$ and \$B\$ being in a particular companion form (which is given in 4.34).

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \alpha _1 I_p & \alpha _2 I_p& \cdots  & \alpha _{r-1} I_p & \alpha _r I_p \\
 I_p & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & I_p & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  & \cdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots  & I_p & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \ \ \ B=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 I_p \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 \vdots  \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now use (4.35), (4.37) and the above form of \$A\$ and \$B\$ to get the following.

$$s\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 Z_1 \\
 Z_2 \\
 Z_3 \\
 \vdots  \\
 Z_r \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \alpha _1 I_p & \alpha _2 I_p& \cdots  & \alpha _{r-1} I_p & \alpha _r I_p \\
 I_p & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & I_p & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  & \cdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots  & I_p & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 Z_1 \\
 Z_2 \\
 Z_3 \\
 \vdots  \\
 Z_r \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 I_p \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 \vdots  \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

And perform block matrix multiplication. Row blocks 2 to the end will give \$s Z_2=Z_1\$, \$s Z_3 =Z_2\$, etc.

This pattern is because row block 2 onward have the identity matrix in the lower off diagonal. This will shift the elements of \$Z\$ one down (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix). And conveniently, all the corresponding elements of \$B\$ are \$0\$.